# Wordpress how to debug a 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: wordpress, debugging, woocommerce

I am working on a wordpress website and I am getting a 504 Gateway Timeout everytime I try to access the customize tab.

I have tried to debug using

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', TRUE );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

And I got nothing.

I have tried to disable some plugins and finally it worked after disabling woocommerce. but I need it for my website

I don't know what I can do to debug and fix this timeout, I've tried everything I know with the wordpress.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not get any error_log file under wp-content directory after settings debug log true?

Comment: You can checkout your wc-logs in your WordPress folder.

Comment: @WordPressMechanic yes i can't find any error_log file

Comment: Last time same issue was reported on a web hosting where this was because of the insufficient server resources. Your parameters are perfect to generate error_log but if still you are unable to find in wp-content directory, please check with your hosting service provider so they can guide you about error_log at least.